# Available snapshots for main net?

Tags: snapshots, mainnet

Are there any freely available recent snapshots for the main net that I could download ?
I'm looking for either full or rolling.

Comment: Can you update the accepted answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given this is the accepted answer, I decided to update this answer.

Based on all the rest of answers as of today (10/10/2021), the following have updated snapshots:

- https://xtz-shots.io/
- https://snapshots-tezos.giganode.io/

Comment: Thank you for your answer and thank you TzDutch! The last snapshot from quicksync is a bit more than one month old. It's already really valuable but something even more recent would be awesome and I was wondering if something like this existed.

Comment: TzDutch are out of business. The quicksync is not available anymore.

Comment: See my answer or check: https://github.com/Phlogi/tezos-snapshots

Comment: Current up-to-date source: https://snapshots-tezos.giganode.io/
This answer should be updated again.

Answer (score 8):

Automated full and rolling snapshots available here: https://github.com/Phlogi/tezos-snapshots

Comment: These are the only snapshots that worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: This snapshot source is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 7):

You can already get full mode snapshots [here](https://tezosshots.com/).

Alphanet Archive and Mainnet Archive coming soon™.

Comment: Thank you! Having all snapshots will be super useful.

Comment: Any update on the Mainnet archive download? i would need it very urgently

Comment: 7-zip compressed Mainnet archive files uploading right now.

Answer (score 5):

There is also: https://snapshots.tulip.tools/#/

with snapshots for full and rolling, and the context and store folders as .tar.gz for archive for all networks ( the tezos node does not yet support export/import of archive snapshots, so thats why .tar.gz )

Answer (score 4):

https://tezos.giganode.io provides access to daily tezos snapshots (full and rolling) via IPFS and web.

https://snapshots-tezos.giganode.io

Answer (score 3):

You have also https://snapshots.baketzfor.me/ for mainnet snapshots.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an update for this question, these snapshots work perfectly when you extract them with `xz`.

https://github.com/Phlogi/tezos-snapshots

**Rolling**

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/Phlogi/tezos-snapshots/releases/latest | jq -r ".assets[] | select(.name) | .browser_download_url" | grep roll | xargs wget -q --show-progress
```

**Full**

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/Phlogi/tezos-snapshots/releases/latest | jq -r ".assets[] | select(.name) | .browser_download_url" | grep full | xargs wget -q --show-progress
# files are splitted as max. size is 2GB on github release assets
# all in one decompress
cat mainnet.full.* | xz -d -v -T0 > mainnet.importme
```

Comment: This snapshot source is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 2):

As of December 2022:

- https://xtz-shots.io/ by Oxhead Alpha has rolling snapshots for mainnet and all test networks including ghostnet
- https://snapshots.tezos.marigold.dev/ by Marigold has rolling and full snapshots, for mainnet, ghostnet and some other test networks
- https://lambsonacid.nl/ by Nomadic Labs has rolling and full snapshots for mainnet and one test network (but not ghostnet)

Answer (score 1):

This is May 2021. Most snapshots providers listed here have stopped updating, and some (tezosshots[.]com) are actually redirecting to questionable sites (at least spam, if not downright malicious).

**These are the only currently updated snapshot providers** that I am aware of (happy to add more to the list and keep it updated.)

- https://mainnet.xtz-shots.io
- https://snapshots-tezos.giganode.io