# Snapshot for alphanet

Tags: alphanet, snapshots

There exists publicly available snapshots for mainnet (see [here](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/q/1385/118) )

Does there exist publicly available snapshot for alphanet ?

Comment: There is one temporarily available at https://ostez.com/snapshots/alphanet-20190630.full.gz

Answer (score 1):

You can already get full mode snapshots [here.](https://tezosshots.com)

Alphanet Archive and Mainnet Archive coming soon™ (maybe till end of this week).

Answer (score 1):

The snapshots for different network and mode:

https://snapshots.tulip.tools/#/