# Rebuild node from sources

Tags: node

I had to rebuild my node. I was finally able to “git clone” the Mainetvbut I couldn’t find a snapshot anywhere. Also, I experienced an error message when I finally tried to import snapshot (MacOS Catalina). Therefore, I have to sync  the node theold way. Is their a repo where snapshots are stored?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/available-snapshots-for-main-net

Comment: The header and the question in the body refer to two different things, ie problems to compile a node from source and where to find a snapshot. Can you please specify your question. However, if you are looking for snapshots, the link in the previous comment leads you to the answer on Tezos SE.