# How do I build a Tezos node and start baking from the sources on Ubuntu?

Tags: node, baking, setup, ubuntu

I'm wondering how to install the Tezos node

Comment: Downloading the full mainnet is broken into multiple pieces now, as its over Github's 2GB limit. After downloading the full snapshot ending in .00 and .01, one must use this command to extract into one file:
```
cat mainnet.full.* | xz -d -v -T0 > mainnet.importme
```
_note: I left the output file suffix as .importme from the updated documentation on Github, just in case the piped output meeting the input regex would break things_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a step by step updated guide on how to build a Tezos node from the sources on Ubuntu, also see my youtube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAHoF-oO71U

DOWNLOADS AND LINKS

Ubuntu download:
https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Tezos node snapshot links:
[Available snapshots for main net?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/available-snapshots-for-main-net)
https://github.com/Phlogi/tezos-snapshots
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/Phlogi/tezos-snapshots/releases/latest | jq -r ".assets[] | select(.name) | .browser_download_url" | grep full | xargs wget -q --show-progress

How To:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-extract-xz-compressed-archive-on-linux
http://tezos.gitlab.io/user/snapshots.html

Tezos node:
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04

Getting Started

### become superuser

sudo su

### update system

sudo su
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

### install curl

sudo apt-get install curl

### say yes to all prompts

### install unizip tools

apt-get install xz-utils

######build  Tezos node from sources

### all one line

sudo apt install -y rsync git m4 build-essential patch unzip bubblewrap wget pkg-config libgmp-dev libev-dev libhidapi-dev
wget https://github.com/ocaml/opam/releases/download/2.0.3/opam-2.0.3-x86_64-linux
sudo cp opam-2.0.3-x86_64-linux /usr/local/bin/opam
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/opam
git clone https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos.git
cd tezos
git checkout mainnet

### type "yes" for opam init command

opam init --bare
make build-deps ## note: process 7 takes a long time
eval $(opam env)
make
export PATH=~/tezos:$PATH
source ./src/bin_client/bash-completion.sh
export TEZOS_CLIENT_UNSAFE_DISABLE_DISCLAIMER=Y

### install jp

sudo apt install -y jq

### install opam

make build-deps
make build-dev-deps ##takes a while
eval $(opam env)
make

## generate tezos node ID ## if the tezos wasn't installed in /home/~, do a search for tezos

cd /home/'username'/tezos/

## download node snapshot(saves you hours)

curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/Phlogi/tezos-snapshots/releases/latest | jq -r ".assets[] | select(.name) | .browser_download_url" | grep full | xargs wget -q --show-progress

## find out th name of the file

ls /

## unzip the file

unxz "name of file"

## rename the file, taking note of the block number, rename to mainnet.full(without semicolons)

mv 'original file name.chain' 'mainnet.full'

## create the tezos node identity, for the --block variable, use the block number located on the

./tezos-node identity generate

## import the snapshot

./tezos-node snapshot import mainnet.full --block BMetLX2em7Q2tbAxcuPbUQNEY4NhRDEZtJCQeoFvWnYwDzb5qGU

## kill original app using the ports(look for port 9732)

sudo lsof -i -P -n
kill -9 'PROCESS NUMBER USING PORT 9732/8732'
sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:8732`

## start the node

./tezos-node run --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1

### note use lsof command if file is locked and then killall to stop the process, or unlock the file by rm the lock file in the path

## wait for node to sync(watch progress with this command

./tezos-client bootstrapped

Your finished!!!

### Setup nano ledger for baking

### Connect ledger and list ledger devices

./tezos-client list connected ledgers

### if using tezbox, copy the line that uses the path "ed25519"

### import ledger key using path found above, create an 'ALIAS' which is any word/number so you don't need to type in the path every time

./tezos-client import secret key 'ALIAS' "ledger://path-determined-in-previous-step"

### get chain ID

./tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/chain_id

### copy output into chain ID below --> example:,NOTE: take out the <>, just use whats inside the brackets

./tezos-client setup ledger to bake for mack --main-chain-id "NetXdQprcVkpaWU"

### start baker

./tezos-baker-005-PsBabyM1 run with local node /root/.tezos-node 'ALIAS'

### start endorser

./tezos-endorser-005-PsBabyM1 run 'ALIAS'

### start accuser

./tezos-accuser-005-PsBabyM1 run

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote and ansible role to do all this on debian machines :
you can check it out here : https://gitlab.com/abate/training-2020-deploy/-/tree/master/ansible

I'm still working on the ssh tunnel that is not super reliable, but the rest seems working.

Comment: Nice! I'll check that out when I have a chance

Answer (score 1):

See http://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtoget.html

It gives instructions for installing Tezos (the node, client, and other tools) in various forms: compiling the sources, precompiled binaries, docker containers, etc.