# Any security issue with snapshots download from internet?

Tags: node

I am trying to run a tezos node, but it takes so long time to bootstrap. It has been a day but it still hasn't finished syncing (I guess it is only around 50% from the timestamp).

I have just known that there is a quick way to start a node if there is a snapshot. In this [link](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/available-snapshots-for-main-net) there are many places to download snapshots. I don't know if it is a wise idea to just download from any of those site, since I worry there may be security issues that can exploit my node.

Anyone know a snapshot from trusted places (e.g. from official tezos website, or official github)?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have an answer, but do you mean to say you are syncing from genesis and after 1 day have got 50% of the blockchain already???  That seems incredible.  Did you compile or are you using binaries or are you using the provided docker images?

Comment: I'm not very sure about your questions, so I provide the full information here: Host node is not a bare metal server, it is a dedicated instant with 2 dedicated core, 120GB SSD, 8GB RAM (from vultr). I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it and follow this instruction to install https://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtoget.html . Then I ran `tezos-node identity generate`, `tezos-node run --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1` (about 26 hours ago). Then `tezos-client bootstrapped` (about 10-11 hours ago). Currently the timestamp is `2019-02-14T09:14:17Z`. Is that very slow or normal? Thanks!

Comment: You have a 120GB SSD, what mode are you using? In archive mode, the node takes close to 200GB.

It takes about 1 week to synchronize a mainnet node in archive mode, with a good machine and good internet connection.

Comment: Running in full mode (default), your node will start syncin'g from others in the P2P network starting 7 cycles in the past. Only an archive mode will start from genesis. See @PhilippeWang answer below. When you import the snapshot, provide the additional parameter of the hash for verification.

Comment: I didn't specify archive or genesis, so I guess it is the default (full mode). Thank you for the information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to trust the provider of the snapshot very much. Once you have imported the snapshot, you can simply check that the hash of a recent block is the same as the hash given by some explorer that you will trust. For instance, if block 1,730,000's hash is BLmKPfoMB6E52tdvTHJsWPHTGG7jUWXiW5yW9pAopEuWgYh69zp on several public explorers and on your node too, then you're good. If the hash doesn't match, then discard and then use another snapshot provider...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand it now.

Comment: You don't even need to import the snapshot before checking that the hash of its head is included on the chain according to explorers.